# Crontab entry not running as expected

Tags: cron, trash, rm

I have setup crontab e with the following line and it is not running every hour on the 14th minute as I expect it should.

```
14 * * * * rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

First, is this code correct?

Secondly, If so why is it not running at all and what do I have to do to get it to do so. I just want to clear the trash hourly is all. I go this code from a best answer here on askabuntu.

thanks

Comment: Who's crontab is it? Does the user have write access to the Trash? And you should always use full paths in crontab, e.g `/bin/rm -rf /home/user/.local/share/Trash/*` (replace user with your username)

Comment: I used sudo crontab e to access con so I'm assuming it's root. I don't know. I assumed it would run as root. I also tried full path and same result. Nothing.

Comment: If you only want to delete your own trash, you do not need to run `crontab` as root; you may define your own crontab. Did you try `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` to see if there are errors reported?

Comment: Command appears to be running hourly as expected, but trash still contains deleted folders. here is syslog line: Dec 20 16:00:01 computer1 CRON[17705]: (norman) CMD (rm -rf /home/norman/.local/share/Trash/*) . this is in user cron, root cron was not deleting either. I don't understand hos its possible for both command to be run AND there being no error on syslog.

Comment: crontab does not report errors on syslog, but via mail if configured. Instead you might change the entry (for testing purposes) to `rm -rv /home/norman/.local/share/Trash/* > /home/norman/cron.log 2>&1` to get the output and error(s) reported in file `~/cron.log`. Do replace `-f`by `-v` here to get information about what is done or what errors occur.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just install Autotrash? Here's the instructions:

First, add the repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bneijt/ppa
```

Then do the update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install Autotrash

```
sudo apt-get install autotrash
```

Sample uses of autotrash:

To purge any file in the trash for more than 30 days being stored, enter the following line in a Terminal window

```
autotrash -d 30
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to use the crontab e, because it is supposed to work and I would like to know why it is not. Adding new repos every time something does not work as it should can yield to security concerns.

Comment: please edit this answer, any edit will do, so that I can change my vote please. System wont let me up vote unless you edit it. I down-voted by mistake and want to remove the down vote by upvoting.